# Module ''meteor/react-meteor-data'' has no exported member 'withTracker'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, meteor, typescript2.0, meteor-react

I am trying to migrate my Meteor-React project to TypeScript. I have a .tsx file:

```
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class Header extends React.Component<any,any> {
...
}

export default withTracker(() => {
  return {
    ...
  };
})(Header);
```

But I am getting the error, even though the site renders correctly:

```
Module ''meteor/react-meteor-data'' has no exported member 'withTracker'.
```

Running versions:

```
Local package version is up-to-date: babel-compiler@7.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: babel-runtime@1.2.2
Local package version is up-to-date: barbatus:typescript@0.6.12
Local package version is up-to-date: barbatus:typescript-compiler@0.9.12
Local package version is up-to-date: barbatus:typescript-runtime@1.0.2
Local package version is up-to-date: ecmascript@0.10.6
Local package version is up-to-date: ecmascript-runtime@0.5.0
Local package version is up-to-date: ecmascript-runtime-client@0.6.2
Local package version is up-to-date: ecmascript-runtime-server@0.5.0
Local package version is up-to-date: meteor@1.8.6
Local package version is up-to-date: react-meteor-data@0.2.16
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you [installed it](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-withTracker) ? `meteor add react-meteor-data`

Comment: Or you have an older version installed

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk yes it is installed and up to date (see running versions section) - I think the problem is due to an old .d.ts type definition about the package, that was missing the withTracker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `react-meteor-data` package does not contain type information. [This repository](https://github.com/meteor-typings/react-meteor-data) contains types for the old `createContainer`, but the repo has not been updated with `withTracker`.

I have solved this by including a `.d.ts` file somewhere in the project with the following declaration:

```
declare module 'meteor/react-meteor-data' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  type RMDComponentConstructor<P> = React.ComponentClass<P> | React.StatelessComponent<P>

  export function withTracker<InP, D, OutP extends (InP & D)>(
    options: (props: InP) => D | {getMeteorData: (props: InP) => D, pure?: boolean}):
    (reactComponent: RMDComponentConstructor<OutP>) => RMDComponentConstructor<InP>;
}
```